# How do you split up source medium path from google analytics in Python?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a year worth of data from Google Analytics Multi-Attribute Funnel API. Example below. The Source Medium comes in with varying lengths and I am looking for ways to create a new column for each channel as ">" the delimiter.

```
20160101    google / organic
20160101    bing / organic
20160101    google / organic > google / organic
20160101    google / organic > google / organic
20160101    (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)
20160101    (direct) / (none) > online.fliphtml5.com / referral
20160101    google / organic > google / organic > (direct) / (none)
20160101    google / organic > (direct) / (none) > google / organic
20160101    google / organic > online.fliphtml5.com / referral > (direct) / (none)
20160101    (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)
20160101    pinterest.com / referral > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)
20160101    google / organic > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none) > google / organic
20160101    bing / organic > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)
20160101    google / organic > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)
```

An example is below of what format I would like the data. How would this be done in Python?

```
Source_Med_Path_1 Source_Med_Path_2....Source_Med_Path_72
google / cpc          direct            google / organic
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at Python's [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using Pandas and apply() functions.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html

My code that takes the source mediums from csv but could just as easily use for API results.

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    #read original data from csv
    data = pd.read_csv('source.csv')

    #split the data on identifier >
    splitdata = data['source'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('>')))
    #join the split data onto transaction data
    data = pd.concat([data['transaction'], splitdata], axis=1, join_axes=[data['transaction'].index])   


    #loop through renaming columns
    cols = ['transaction']    
    for i in range(len(data.columns) -1):
        cols.append('Source_Med_Path_' + str(i+1))

    data.columns = cols        


    #output data    
    print(data)
    data.to_csv('output.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```